# Can I run a CodeIgniter project inside a Laravel one?

Tags: .htaccess, laravel, codeigniter

I have a website that is currently using Laravel but i need to put inside a previous project made on codeigniter inside the website.
So my question is ...

How can i make the two frameworks work nicely with each other.

On my previous site I would use the route www.exampledomain.com/codeigniterproject and I would be redirected to a view that was inside the codeigniter project and handled by the controller.

But currently when I try to do this I get a 500 error.

I have an href trying to point to codeigniterfolder and I get the generic Laravel error "Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found."
When i click on the link.

codeigniterfolder

My ftp looks like this ...

**public_html** where i have all the laravel public directory
   **laravelproject** where everything that my laravel project requires
   and then inside that folder i have the codeigniter one so the folders look like this **laravelproject/codeigniterproject**

Everything is set on the laravel side i have no problems with my routes or whatsoever inside laravel.
But I dont want to migrate all the codeigniter code to laravel it's just not an option, so I wanna integrate the codeigniter project inside my current laravel one.

Comment: Oops... misspelled project. 
My apologies.

Comment: Could you show us some code? What have you done so far?

Comment: You can't make them work nicely, both projects need 2 different apache configuration to begin with. So use 2 seperate virtual hosts on apache and use redirection if you're goal is running them on the same server.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot have 2 `index.php` files in the same app, but you can change  `index.php` to bootstrap Laravel or Codeigniter, according to some conditions you will set. It's not good, but it's doable.

But, really, there are many ways of doing this, the best one would be using your webserver (Nginx, Apache) and have it rewrite the url and send you to the Laravel directory or Codeigniter one accordingly.

What you cand do in Laravel is to configure a Redirect route to send to your old app, in a different VirtualHost (webserver, again):

```
Route::get('/oldapp', function() {
    return Redirect::to('http://google.com');
});
```

Comment: I understand what you mean and I think this is the simplest thing to do but just to be clear. 
I would need to have an active domain to use this redirect right?
I mean i will need to have another domain pointing to the ftp where the codeigniter will be hosted.
I have the ip of the ftp but right now it's not visible via browser because i don't have a domain pointing to it.

Comment: No, as I said in the answer, your webserver is able to control different urls for different sites in very same domain, you don't need a new domain.

Comment: The codeigniter project was hosted in other server and right now it doesn't have a domain so i can't reach it via browser.
The only thing i have its connection via ftp with the ip of that server would laravel will be able to redirect to a site that doesn't have domain?
I'm sorry if i sound stupid or annoying but im really new with server and domains stuff.
I really appreciate ur help.

Comment: How would Laravel access it then? Via FTP it would not access it, so if you need to serve that site, you'll need to get it up on a server with a domain. Or bring it to the current server, with your new app, right?

Comment: Yeah i have laravel running in a server well configured with a domain and everything its alright but the other ftp where I have the codeigniter currenlty doesn't have a domain. 
So my question was and I think its pretty obvious but better safe than sorry...
I need to set a new domain for this ftp in order to use the redirect from the routes of laravel like the example you provided.
Or in other scenario I think I can make a subdomain on my current domain and make the same redirect right?

Comment: If you can bring those old files to the new server and if you know how to configure the webserver you don't even need a subdomain, you can use `youdomain.com` for the new app and `youdomain.com/oldapp` for the old one without having conflicts with the new, and make Laravel to redirect to it.

Comment: All right I think I get it now, thank you for all the help and insides that you gave me. I'm going to dig inside the ftp to configure this properly.
Have a wonderful day Antonio.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not really necessary to be in one directory, why don't you use subdomain?
You can put it simply like this:
on your laravel let's say [www.yoursite.com](http://www.yoursite.com)
and on your codeigniter codeigniter.yoursite.com